# Java: establish SSL connection without authentication

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I am trying to create an application where I have a server that hosts files and a client that wants to retrieve those files.

I am currently trying to establish a SSL connection between the client and the server, however, I only want the encryption part of SSL not the authentication (I do not want to go through the troubles of creating and managing keystores etc).

All the sample code I have found has used TLS which requires authentication. I was wondering what implementation does not use authentication? I read that there is a Diffie Hellman handshake but I was wondering if there was any other cipher suite besides TLS I could use?

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = null;
    try {
    SSLContext ctx;
    KeyManagerFactory kmf;
    KeyStore ks;
    char[] passphrase = "passphrase".toCharArray();

    ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

is there a different SSLContext I could use that will not require me to create a KeyManagerFactory or a Keystore?

Comment: is that what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914033/java-secure-socket-without-authentication

Comment: Note that man in the middle attacks are possible without at least authenticating one side. This means that you are not even attaining confidentiality of information. Unfortunately, if eavesdropping is possible then it is likely that man-in-the-middle is also possible, e.g. when using WiFi connections. IE fully anonymous TLS is useless except for testing purposes in my opinion. I would rather go for self signed certificates myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this and you have some other means of avoiding the man in the middle attacks you will now be vulnerable to, just enable the anonymous cipher suites.